# How to handle when a valued mentor resigns?

Tags: resignation, leadership

So, my favourite boss has resigned. I worked under him for only three months but have had a good rapport with him. It's been two years now that we both are in different projects. Yet, he gave extremely good technical and career advice, whenever I asked for. In short, he is a true leader and not a mere manager.

There were some decisions taken by the higher management and I did anticipate his resignation. But, when he actually resigned, I feel more sad, almost at the verge of crying.

I have been reading articles about what to do when our favourite boss leaves the company, but may be I don't want to accept it.

One of the worries is definitely about not receiving good technical and career advice. Also, he'd put people in their place who might otherwise behave like vultures. They might get promoted now so there's a good chance that the workplace might become toxic. I am not in any leadership role; I only code.

How do I handle losing a valued mentor and avoid the workplace culture suffering as a result?

Comment: The questions as it is now is a bit too open-ended and opinion-based. You could try to make it more tangible/actionable? One solution to your situation: ask that boss where he is going next, and ask if he could take you with him.

Comment: what exactly are you worried about?

Comment: @esther about not receiving good technical and career advice; he'd put people in their place, else most of the other people behave like vultures 

Comment: not receiving advice, or surviving at your workplace without someone to protect you? these are very different things.

Comment: If you're worried about how to deal with specific actions of your workmates without your boss to help you, then [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/184592/edit) your post to reflect that question, and I'm sure people have something to say

Comment: I've made some edits to clarify and remove some of the off-topic elements (asking for personal experience often leads to close votes as polling questions for instance). I still recommend [edit]ing it further since it's not fully clear what your key concerns are and what kind of input you're looking for. If the question is really "how do I emotionally deal with losing someone I valued so much?", I wonder whether it's truly answerable here.

Comment: @esther edited it

Comment: @Linienthal I guess we both edited at the same time, so my changes had overwritten yours. Please edit it, if needed.

Comment: Crossed edits indeed, no worries. :) I've edited it again but feel free to continue improving or adjust it if it's not fully accurate now. You might also want to specify if you're in any kind of leadership position (in which case you could help combat the culture change you worry about) or not (in which case you might need to wait and see and figure out if the culture has changed too much for you).

Comment: @Linienthal it is on an emotional side as well. But, I edited the question for a professional advice.

Comment: @Sara If the key concern is then about the departure of this manager giving free reign to the backstabbing / two-faced part of the culture, consider editing out some of the more emotional aspects (it's an interesting aspect but hard to answer in a general fashion).

Comment: Even if you don't follow him, there's no reason you couldn't stay in touch. He wouldn't be able to put in a word for you at your current company, but he could still give you career advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Follow him.**

It's not that common that you'll run into these kinds of people. We so rarely interact with other people who genuinely improve our lives in measurable ways.

It's worth trying to keep tabs on them, in a friendly and mutually beneficial way.

Reach out to him. A simple "So, what's next for you?" goes a long way.

A few times in my life, I've had people I mentored go the extra step to thank me and share with me how my advice improved their lives.

**This positive feedback was so special to me that I think about it often and it fills me with happiness.**

It's really honestly rare to hear genuinely good stories about how you've improved someone's life. I'd bet your former boss would eat that up with a spoon.

Tell him how much it meant to you professionally. Ask him if you can serve as a reference. Ask him where he's going next and think strongly about following him.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I handle losing a valued mentor and avoid the workplace culture suffering as a result?

Move on. Look forward.

Focus on your goals, work, and your performance. You can keep you eyes open for other potential good mentoring resources around you.

It's unlikely that departure of a single person will fundamental change culture or the way people work. Of course the will be some change, there always is. Just monitor it and react to it objectively using your goals as guidance. Address any potential problems one by one as they occur.